# Why can I not use sjp.glm for plotting log odds for my glmm? Is there any alternative for it?

Tags: sjplot, glmm

I tried using sjp.glm to plot my log odds but I saw that that the function was removed according to this page https://github.com/strengejacke/sjPlot/releases. Is there any alternative I could use? I want to graph individual log odds for all variables in the model and I need help. I would appreciate the help.

I tried the sjp.glm formula for my model but R doesn't let me run it. I have sjPlots installed and loaded but it doesn't work. sjp.glm doesn't exist in my R.